# Error when making API call to MS Graph via botbuilder-js SDK

Tags: node.js, azure-active-directory, botframework, microsoft-graph-api

I wrote a [partial TypeScript version](https://github.com/zarak/testbots/tree/master/typescript/graphbot) of the [msgraph sample code](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/24.bot-authentication-msgraph) from the botbuilder samples repo.

I followed the instructions to do the configuration on Azure [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=aadv2%2Cjavascript%2Cbot-oauth). I used version 2.0 of the Azure AD endpoint.

I used a common tenant and was successfully able to log-in via the bot, but when I try to make a graph API call using `getMe` (by sending the message 'me' to the bot),

```js
    async getMe(): Promise<User> {
        return await this.graphClient
            .api('/me')
            .get().then((res) => {
                return res;
            });
    }
```

I receive an error:

```
GraphError {
  statusCode: -1,
  code: null,
  message: null,
  requestId: null,
  date: 2019-05-13T06:21:12.721Z,
  body: null }
```

I expect that this would successfully return the following message by getting the `displayName` field from the graph API call,

```
You are ${ me.displayName } and you report to nobody.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Downgrade the @microsoft/microsoft-graph-client to specifically version 1.0.0 in your package.json. There is a bug that is present is all subsequent versions of that package that has yet to be corrected.

For clarity's sake, there are a couple later versions that do appear to correct this issue *however* other bugs then appear. The only working one, in my experience, has been the original version.